# Vim delay after press Enter

Tags: vim, ubuntu-14.04

Whenever I press `Enter` vim freezes for a second or so. I tried setting `timeoutlen` to values like `100` but this barely solves the problem — it becomes difficult to enter command sequences.
I use `VIM 7.4` under `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.
Thanks in advance.

**UPD**
[Here's my .vimrc file](http://pastebin.com/J0Z7QRHb)
As you can see I have several plugins. Also there's nothing strange in `top`

**UPD2**
It seems like the issue is about sessions. There are no lags if I open any number of tabs and so. But if I run `:source ~/vim_session` the problem appears.

**UPD3**
The problem has gone after switching to GVim and reinstalling all plugins. But I am still curious what would cause such problem.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing vim? What does your .vimrc looking like? Do you have any vim plugins that might be bogging things down? Have you tried looking at a `top` while using vim? Maybe disk wait time goes up or something abnormal happens.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I updated the question

Comment: I'd recommend that you rename your .vimrc to .vimrc.old start up vim and see if you still have the issue. If the problems are gone, put your .vimrc back and start disabling the plugins one at a time until you find a culprit. I'd bet one of the plugins is causing a problem.

Comment: `let g:user_emmet_leader_key="<C-m>"`: <c-m> is the same as enter. I don't know what this variable is for, but as a 'leader', vim is probably waiting for another keypress after <c-m>.

Comment: You could try commenting out your plugins, do a `:BundleClean`, restart vim and see if that solves the issue.  If it does, you can do a binary search to find the culprit (start by re-enabling half the plugins, test again, if it's still good, then re-enable half the remaining plugins, etc..)

Comment: @Landen with blank `.vimrc` the problem is still there. Here's the thing: when I just star vim (e.g. `vim script.py`) the problem is gone even with my old `.vimrc`. But when I load the session the problem appears. And it's not about many files being open: if I make all the tabs by hand then there's no lags. But if I `:source ~/vim_session` lags start.

Comment: @Neil I tried change it with `<C-n>` — didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have an insert-mode mapping for `<CR>` (`<C-m>` and `<Enter>` are synonyms). Check with

```
:verbose imap <CR>
```

By default, *sessions* capture custom mappings, too. This can cause issues; you can turn that off (for new sessions!) via

```
:set sessionoptions-=options
```

For the existing session, remove / edit out the mappings from it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just checked, and no, I don't have any `<cr>` mappings in neither of modes. `:verbose imap <CR>` says that there is no mappings found.

Comment: I just discovered that I in fact used `<C-m>` in one of bindings. I tried to set it back again and ugly delay started to bother me. Thanks for help!